# Does Python have an equivalent of Perl's qq?

Tags: python, perl

Using `qq`, Perl allows almost any character to be used as quotation marks to define strings containing `'` and `"` without needing to escape them:

```
qq(She said, "Don't!")
qq¬And he said, "I won't."¬
```

(especially handy since my keyboard has `¬` which is almost never used).

Does Python have an equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't define arbitrary characters as quotes, but if you need to use both `'` and `"` within a string you can do so with a multiline string:

```python
>>> """She said "that's ridiculous" and I agreed."""
'She said "that\'s ridiculous" and I agreed.'
```

Note, however, that Python will get confused if the quote type you use is also the last character in the string:

```python
>>> """He yelled "Whatever's the matter?""""
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

so you'd have to switch in that case:

```python
>>> '''He yelled "Whatever's the matter?"'''
'He yelled "Whatever\'s the matter?"'
```

---

Purely as an alternative, you could split the string up into parts that do and don't have each quote type and rely on Python implicitly joining consecutive strings:

```python
>>> "This hasn't got double quotes " 'but "this has"'
'This hasn\'t got double quotes but "this has"'
>>> "This isn't " 'a """very""" "attractive" approach'
'This isn\'t a """very""" "attractive" approach'
```

Comment: That's great! I never thought of that use of the triple quote. But what if I need to have 3 consecutive "s and 3 consecutive 's in the string?! * ducks *

Comment: @Gnubie then you're hosed!

Comment: @Gnubie I've added an alternative that would allow that (it's a bit ugly, though)

Comment: Thanks, Jon. I accept this answer for the string concatenation.

Comment: @Gnubie I'm sure future readers of your code will thank me ;)

Answer (score 5):

You could use triple single quotes or triple double quotes.

```py
>>> s = '''She said, "Don't!"'''
>>> print(s)
She said, "Don't!"
>>> s = """'She sai"d, "Don't!'"""
>>> print(s)
'She sai"d, "Don't!'
```

Comment: Sadly, the SO highlighting doesn't know about `'''` being a string delimiter :)

Answer (score 1):

I just asked myself where is quote() method in python? Particularly Perl's qXXX sugar. Found one quote() in urllib but this is not what I wanted - that is to simply quote string in the string itself. And then it hit me:

```
some_string = repr(some_string)
```

repr built-in will always quote string properly. It will get single quoted though. Perl had a tendency to double-quote.